# XSLT string replace, multiple strings

Tags: xslt

I want to implement find and replace string using xslt 1.0.
The problem is, I have to replace multiple strings with different values.. For example, my input xml is as below

```
<process xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/ErrorHandler" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/ErrorHandler">
    <client:result>The city name is $key1$ and Country name is $key2$   </client:result>
</process>
```

result should be

```
<process xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/ErrorHandler" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/ErrorHandler">
    <client:result>The city name is London and Country name is England  </client:result>
</process>
```

$key1$ and $key2$ from the input string should be replaced with London and England.
I found many examples to find and replace single string, but I am not sure how to replace multiple strings with different value..
Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See one possible method here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527077/change-html-dynamically-thru-xsl/33529970#33529970

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much easier if you could use XSLT 2.0 or higher. It could be as simple as:

```
replace(replace(., '\$key1\$', 'London'), '\$key2\$', 'England')
```

However, if you are stuck with XSLT 1.0, you could [use a recursive template to perform the replace](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/replace.html#d8770e61), and invoke it for each of the tokens you want to replace(using the product of the previous calls as input to the next):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/ErrorHandler"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template name="replace-string">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="replace"/>
        <xsl:param name="with"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$with"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text"
                        select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$with"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="client:result">
        <xsl:variable name="orig" select="string(.)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="key1">
            <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$orig"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'$key1$'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="with" select="'London'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="key2">
            <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$key1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'$key2$'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="with" select="'England'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="$key2"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```